# GraphQL + Springboot + Http Headers

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, graphql, graphql-java

I'm using these graphql dependencies:

```
    "com.graphql-java-kickstart:graphql-spring-boot-starter:12.0.0",
    "com.graphql-java-kickstart:graphql-java-tools:12.0.0",
```

And how can I get httpRequestHeaders from the DataFetchingEnvironment class. I see `DataFetchingEnvironment.getContext()` is deprecated is there any other alternative?

Current logic:

```
        GraphQLServletContext servletContext = env.getContext(); //deprecated

        GraphQLContext qlContext = env.getGraphQlContext(); // No httpRequest

        var httpRequest = servletContext.getHttpServletRequest();
```

Comment: There is one option I found, we can introduce custom Filter, but I don't know how write test cases for it

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
env.getGraphQlContext().get(HttpServletRequest.class).getHeader("header")
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31700540)

Answer (score 0):

As of 12.0.0, environment.getGraphQLContext() is not supported. This lack of support is referenced in the project's github (https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/graphql-spring-boot/issues/808)

As of version 13.0.0, you can access the HttpServletRequest by using

```
HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = environment.getGraphQlContext().get(HttpServletRequest.class);
```

If you need to use version 12.0.0, my suggestion would be to use a OncePerRequestFilter and store the header information you need in a ThreadLocal value. Just remember to clear that thread local value after the request has been processed. This will only work if you turn off "async mode" that the GraphQL library introduced in 11.0.0, as "async mode" processes the request filters and graphql resolvers in different threads.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to 13.0.0 (or 14.0.0) and call

HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = env.getGraphQlContext().get(HttpServletRequest.class);

This will give you and HttpServletRequest, from where you can call

```
private static Map<String, String> getHeadersFromRequest(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        var mapOfHeaders = new HashMap<String, String>();

        Enumeration<String> headerNames = httpServletRequest.getHeaderNames();
        if (headerNames != null) {
            while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
                String headerName = headerNames.nextElement();
                mapOfHeaders.put(headerName, httpServletRequest.getHeader(headerName));
            }
        }
        return mapOfHeaders;
    }
```

to return a list map of headers.